# Which version of SASS is my WebCompiler extension using?

Tags: sass, web-compiler

I'm using the [WebCompiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler) extension for VS and I'm trying to find out what version of SASS it's using. I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I've tried looking in the extension information (in VS), on the [github repo](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler), and in the [changelog](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Now I'm wondering if it uses on internal version of SASS of if it references it from somewhere else.

Please can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like the latest `node-sass`

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/blob/586295ba3c3107b7613dcb5a02667aad817045d4/build/build.cmd#L18