# Why does @use not work in Web Compiler Visual Studio extension?

Tags: sass, web-compiler

I'm running Visual Studio 2019 (16.3.9) using the Web Compiler extension (1.12.394) to compile scss files.

Here is a simple case that works. I have a file - test.scss:

```
$color: blue;

.button {
    background-color: $color;
}
```

This gets compiled to this:

```
.button {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But if I try and do something like what is outlined here - https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use#configuring-modules - it doesn't seem to work. I create another file - _base.scss:

```
$color: red !default;

.button {
    background-color: $color;
}
```

Then I change my test.scss file to this:

```
@use 'base' with (
  $color: blue
);
```

I expected that the compiled output would be the same as the original example:

```
.button {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But this is what I get:

```
@use 'base' with (
  $color: blue
);
```

My guess is that the compiler is not happy with the @use rule, but I don't see any errors. _base.scss & test.scss are in the same directory. I'm only new to Sass, but surely this should be possible?

Comment: Sass modules are still pretty new, it could be that web-compiler doesn't have the Sass version that supports it yet.

Answer (score 6):

This is filed as an issue on Web Compiler on GitHub:
[@use does not work](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/441)

The response is:

> @use its currently supported only by dart-sass and other platforms use
>   @import for now so this is not a Web Compiler issue

I am also new to Sass, and I can't figure out how to tell what version of Sass is supported in Web Compiler. (Edit: Just found SO question [Which version of SASS is my WebCompiler extension using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232213/which-version-of-sass-is-my-webcompiler-extension-using))

Frustrating, because I am struggling with preventing duplicated CSS from @imports and it seems like @use is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, I'm new to Sass so was jumping straight in with the latest features. My first hunch, as mentioned by @Bauke, is that the current version of Web Compiler doesn't support @use (and other new features of Sass).

Based on this, I opted for a workaround with currently supported features that achieves the same result.

_base.scss:

```
$color: red !default;

.button {
    background-color: $color;
}
```

test.scss:

```
$color: blue;
@import 'base';
```

Compiled output:

```
.button {
    background-color: blue;
}
```